# Redux - if property from state is null (Typeerror)

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

If I'm trying to get a value from a property from state, and there is no such property, I get `TypeError: state.session.user.designer.account is null`

```
ShopSetupForm = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: {
             account_bank: state.session.user.designer.account.bank
```

So in the case where state.session.user.designer.account is not set in state, those values I'm trying to set is null and the page doesn't load.

Should I make some condition? This didn't work:

```
account_bank: state.session.user.designer.account.bank || ''
```

or

```
 account_bank: state.session.user.designer.account.bank ? state.session.user.designer.account.bank : ''},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you're trying to access the property `bank` from `state.session.user.designer.account` when it's `null`. In that case, the fix would be to check if the value is not `null` and then access the property:

```
account_bank: state.session.user.designer.account && state.session.user.designer.account.bank
```

(this would evaluate to `account_bank: null`) or

```
account_bank: state.session.user.designer.account ? state.session.user.designer.account.bank : ''
```

(which would evaluate to `account_bank: ''`).